# DataBinding with SfGauge

Tags: c#, xamarin, binding, syncfusion, gauge

Would anyone know if its possible to bind data to a SfGauge?
If so how according to the needle pointer value,

```
NeedlePointer needlePointer = new NeedlePointer();
needlePointer.Value = 60;
needlePointer.Color = Color.Gray;
needlePointer.KnobColor = Color.FromHex("#2bbfb8");
needlePointer.Thickness = 5;
needlePointer.KnobRadius = 20;
needlePointer.LengthFactor = 0.8;
scale.Pointers.Add(needlePointer);
```

Thanks

Here is my Updated code however still showing zero on the guage.

```
namespace Drip
{


    public partial class Guage : ContentPage
    {
        private const string Url = "https://thingspeak.com/channels/301726/field/1.json";
        private HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();
        private ObservableCollection<Feed> _data2;



        SfCircularGauge circular;
        NeedlePointer needlePointer;

        public Guage()
        {
          ...

            needlePointer = new NeedlePointer();

            needlePointer.Color = Color.Gray;
            needlePointer.KnobColor = Color.FromHex("#2bbfb8");
            needlePointer.Thickness = 5;
            needlePointer.KnobRadius = 20;
            needlePointer.LengthFactor = 0.8;






            scale.Pointers.Add(needlePointer);

            Content = circular;
        }


        protected override async void OnAppearing()
        {
            var content = await _client.GetStringAsync(Url);
            var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(content);
            _data2 = new ObservableCollection<Feed>(data.Feeds);

            this.BindingContext = _data2[0];

            needlePointer.SetBinding(Pointer.ValueProperty, "Field1");




        }
    }
```

Model

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace Drip
{
    public class Feed : INotifyPropertyChanged

    {
        private decimal _field1 = 0;
        public decimal Field1

        {
            get
            {
                return _field1;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_field1 != value)
                {
                    _field1 = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }


            }


        } 
        public DateTime Created_at { get; set; }
        public int Entry_id { get; set; }


        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyField1 = null)
        {
            {
                var handler = PropertyChanged;
                if (handler != null)
                {
                    PropertyChangedEventArgs propertyChangedEvent
                    = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyField1);
                    handler(this, propertyChangedEvent);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have changed the following above to my code however the guage is still showing value zero, have i missed anything or used something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

assuming you want to bind to the property "Value" of your BindingContext

```
needlePointer.SetBinding(NeedlePointer.ValueProperty, "Value");
```

in order for data binding to work, you need to set a BindingContext

```
this.BindingContext = _data2[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

The value which we are getting for `_data2[0]` from `json` is `0`. Please refer the following attached screenshot of the json data.

In the [attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LbXQo.png) screenshot, highlighted the `field1` item value of 0th index from the collection. 
 So, if you bound those value with the needle pointer it will show only the `0` value. Can you please ensure what value you are getting from `_data2[0]`? If you are getting 0 then please get the `field1` value from `_data[1]` or `_data[2]`.